# Javascript function details

Tags: javascript

I have a function in javascript

```
function Ob(a)
{
  a.j.a.r(a);
  return a
}
```

Can anyone detail what a.j.a.r() does?

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like minified code. `a`, `j`, `a`, and `r` are all properties whose names have been shrunk to save space when publishing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each dot reference is a property reference on an object.  So:

```
a.j.a.r(a);
```

It works like this in words:

1. Start with object `a`.
2. Get the `.j` property on that object.
3. On the object from the `.j` property, get the `.a` property on that object.
4. On the object from this second `.a` property, get the `.r` property on that object.
5. Execute that value as a function and pass it the original `a` value.

In pieces, it is like this:

```
var x = a.j;
var y = x.a;
var z = y.r;
z(a);
```